# Find the distance between one point and each point in a list, return the distance of the closest point from list

Tags: r

I'm attempting to find the distance between my original point and each point that is in a list.

I found a function someone else produced on here:

`euc.dist <- function(x1, x2) sqrt(sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2))`

But this appears to sum up the distance of ALL the points from the list.

I would like to have it either return the distance from the first point to each point in the list, or just return which point from that list is the closest to the original point.

```
referencePointX <- c(102.54)
referencePointY <- c(45.30)

pointListX <- c(76.12, 81.76...)

pointListY <- c(30.13, 39.95...)
```

Should result in:

```
30.465477
21.457654
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Added reproducible example.

Comment: Do you need this for an arbitrary number `n` of dimensions, or are you sticking with just two dimensions: namely `x` and `y`?

Comment: Just the two dimensions of x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the points in a matrix `mat` with one row per point, you can use `dist(mat)` to get the distance between every pair of rows. To get the distances from the first row, just select the first `nrow(other_points)` (i.e. number of other points) distances with `head`.

```r
referencePoint <- c(102.54, 45.30)
pointListX <- c(76.12, 81.76)
pointListY <- c(30.13, 39.95)

other_points <- cbind(pointListX, pointListY)
mat <- rbind(referencePoint, other_points)
mat
#>                pointListX pointListY
#> referencePoint     102.54      45.30
#>                     76.12      30.13
#>                     81.76      39.95
head(dist(mat), nrow(other_points))
#> [1] 30.46548 21.45765
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>